# Multi-Threading Client-Server Chat application in java

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets

When I close client it gives me error on server side

> Like :      java.net.SocketException: Connection reset   at
>   java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:196)   at
>   java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:122)   at
>   java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:210)   at
>   java.io.DataInputStream.readLine(DataInputStream.java:513)    at
>   HServer.run(HServer.java:28)

Checkout the code and please tell me how can I send one message of client to all other      clients using threads please help me guys :)

```
ClientDemo.java

import java.io.*;
import java.net.Socket;

/*
* To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
* and open the template in the editor.
*/

/**
*
* @author zain-mughal
*/
public class ClientDemo extends javax.swing.JFrame {
DataInputStream input;
PrintWriter output;
public void Connect(){
    try {
        Socket s = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 2111);
        input=new DataInputStream(s.getInputStream());
        output=new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream());
        boolean more_data=true;
        while(more_data){
            String in=input.readLine();
            if(in==null){
                more_data=false;
            }
            else{
                System.out.println(in);
            }
        }
        s.close();
        input.close();
        output.close();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
       ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
public static void main(String args[]){
   ClientDemo obj=new ClientDemo();
   obj.Connect();

}

}

HServer.java

import java.io.*;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

/*
* To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
* and open the template in the editor.
*/

/**
*
* @author zain-mughal
*/
public class HServer extends Thread {
Socket AcceptReQ;
public HServer(Socket reqAccept) {
    this.AcceptReQ=reqAccept;
}
@Override
public void run(){
    try {
        DataInputStream input = new DataInputStream(AcceptReQ.getInputStream());
        PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(AcceptReQ.getOutputStream());
        String in=null;
        while((in=input.readLine())!=null){
                System.out.println(in);
        }

        AcceptReQ.close();
        input.close();
        output.close();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
 public static void main(String args[]){
    try {
        ServerSocket req = new ServerSocket(2111);

        while(true){
            Socket reqAccept=req.accept();
            Thread t=new HServer(reqAccept);
            t.start();
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(HServer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Your client connects to the server, and waits for it to send some data (`input.readLine()`). The server meanwhile accepts the connection, and waits for the client to send something (also `input.readLine()`). So, they are both just sitting there doing nothing, and waiting on each other. What do you expect to happen?

Comment: Using one thread per connection is not going to scale well - read up on java.nio.channels.Selector

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

[Build a robust Java server](https://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=java&seqNum=237)

[Building a basic Echo Server and A ChatServer](https://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=java&seqNum=238)

I used this as base for my own server.
It's a little bit old and many Java features are not used but it works great.

Take some time to comprehend it.